# How do I stop Django Channels from killing my long-running view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-channels

I have a Django project that uses Django Channels.

Django version 2.2.10.

Django Channels version 2.3.0.

The app I'm working on at the moment does NOT use Django Channels - other apps in the same projects use it.

The App I'm working on has a simple view:

```
def generate_usage_report(request):
    time.sleep(300)
    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

This view is being run by an AJAX request, so I don't care that it takes 5 minutes to return - the user's browser is showing a loading bar until it is done.

Unfortunately, after about 30 seconds (give or take), I get this in my logs:

```
WARNING  Application instance <Task pending coro=<AsgiHandler.__call__() running at /opt/my_project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/http.py:192> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/futures.py:403, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f02891c44c8>()]>> for connection <WebRequest at 0x7f02891c20f0 method=GET uri=/my_requested_page clientproto=HTTP/1.0> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

And the Ajax call never completes, since the function call is killed prematurely. Is there some way to let it run until it completes?

Answer (score 0):

You should never! to `time.sleep` on a server. What this does is stop python for that amount of time. ALL of python (including other views) and any async runloop that you are within.

I would suggest moving this view to be an AsyncHTTPConsumer in channels, then make user that nothing you are doing blocks python. (in short if you do anything that takes any real time it should be `await`ed).

if you need to call ba block a sync code then you can use :

```
  executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
  await loop.run_in_executor(executor, your_big_blocking_funtion)
```